# Unable to find setter method for attribute - weblogic with eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, jakarta-ee, weblogic

I am getting the exception in the title for some attribute of a custom tag. This happens when I run the application locally with eclipse indigo (Weblogic 10.3.3).

Now obviously the setter method exists, so I am not sure what the problem is. I am also able to resolve this issue by cleaning the project (using the Project->Clean option), which re-compiles all the .java files in the project and takes a lot of time (I also have to restart the server and redeploy the application for this).

Is there a a less annoying way to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

I know this behavior from Rational Software Architect (Eclipse 3.6 based, WebSphere) and Eclipse < Version 4 (with GlassFish).

First: Eclipse 4 (or Rational software version >= 9 which bases on Eclipse 4.2.2) makes a lot of things better. Try to update if not already on Juno.
Second: Turn of the hot deployment. The behavior you see is a mix up of old and new sources which explains why a clean does fix the problem. The simple question is if you really really need  hotdeployment...

Comment: I kind of do need hot deployment since every restart to the server takes about 2-3 minutes. 
I found another way of fixing this - I make a small change (add a space) to the relevant JSP file and this forces recompilation.

However, this problem still occurs sometimes on remote servers when I deploy an .ear generated by eclipse (using the export ear option). 

You are saying that this is related to the eclipse version and can be solved by migrating to Juno/Kepler?

Comment: It's worth a shot. The upgrade solved the problems regarding hotdeployment for the team Eclipse / Maven / GlassFish... I know - not exactly what you asked for but nevertheless a proof of concept.